# Phoenix Sorcerer in Pathfinder Society Play

Tags: pathfinder-2e, sorcerer, pathfinder-society

The [Phoenix Bloodline](https://2e.aonprd.com/Bloodlines.aspx?ID=15) for sorcerer is marked as [PFS Limited](https://2e.aonprd.com/PFS.aspx) which states:

> A limited option is rarer in Society play, but not unheard of. A limited option can be selected only if specifically allowed by a boon—whether from the Achievement Points system, a Chronicle Sheet, or another other option from a Pathfinder Society source—even if the option is common or if the character meets the normal prerequisites or access requirements printed in the option’s source.

Its not marked as restricted but I cannot find a boon for either of the three options listed. Does a way to play this bloodline exist or is it some kind of future proofing so that the bloodline could be chosen in the future?

Answer (score 10):

The Phoenix Bloodline is from the third book of Fists of the Ruby Phoenix, [King of the Mountain](https://paizo.com/products/btq027sq?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-168-King-of-the-Mountain). If you play or run that third book and receive a chronicle, you can purchase the chronicle boon Touched by the Phoenix, which grants access to the Phoenix Bloodline. The chronicle grants access for all of your characters, so it doesn't need to be applied to a specific character.